# ASP.NET Core "CreatedAtRoute" Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Inside my ASP.NET Core app I have a controller action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSubscriber([FromBody] SubscriberDef subscriber)
{
    //...implementation removed

    var link = Url.Link("SubscriberLink", new { id = subscriber.ID });
        return Created(link, null);
}
```

The above code works as expected.  However, if I use the built-in method "CreatedAtRoute", then I get an exception:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSubscriber([FromBody] SubscriberDef subscriber)
{
    //...implementation removed

    return CreatedAtRoute("SubscriberLink", new { id = subscriber.ID });
}
```

The exception is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

The exception causes the service to return a 500 status code.

It is the same route in either case, so I don't know why the first example works correctly and the second does not.

My `project.json` contains this:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx46": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

For reference sake, the named route is composed from two pieces.  First is the controller prefix:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SubscribersController : Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Second is the GET action, where the actual `"SubscriberLink"` route is named:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "SubscriberLink")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(Subscriber))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSubscriber(Guid id)
{
    //...implementation removed...
    return Ok(subscriber);
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Where is the `SubscriberLink` route name defined?

Comment: @haim770 It is defined in the very last code snippet.

Comment: Does `var link = Url.Link("SubscriberLink", new { id = subscriber.ID });` return the correct Url or just not throwing exception?

Comment: This is a great example of a well-researched and well-explained question. Cheers!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## Short Answer

You are using the wrong overload of `CreatedAtRoute`. Use the overload that takes three arguments instead.

## Working Example

For instance, the following works on my machine.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SubscribersController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var subscriber = new
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            FirstName = "Shaun",
            LastName = "Luttin"
        };

        // overload with three arguments
        return CreatedAtRoute(
            routeName: "SubscriberLink",
            routeValues: new { id = subscriber.Id },
            value: subscriber);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "SubscriberLink")]
    public IActionResult GetSubscriber(Guid id)
    {
        var subscriber = new
        {
            Id = id,
            FirstName = "Shaun",
            LastName = "Luttin"
        };

        return new JsonResult(subscriber);
    }
}
```

## Details

The result is a 201 response. The response's body contains details of the entity we created (the `value` argument) and the response's Location header contains a URI to the entity.

[image: The response includes the obj we created and its location.]

There are three overloads for `CreatedAtRoute`.

```
CreatedAtRoute(object routeValues, object value)
CreatedAtRoute(string routeName, object value)
CreatedAtRoute(string routeName, object routeValues, object value)
```

If we want to pass a route name and route values, we use the overload that takes three arguments. If we do not want to return details of the entity we created, we can pass `null` for the third argument,

Comment: It should be [Route("api/[controller]", Name = "SubscriberLink")] because in your case you are setting the route template, not the name.

Comment: That's incorrect. The new `HttpGetAttribute` *does* define a `Name` property and also implements `IRouteTemplateProvider` that provides the route name

Comment: @haim770 Fixed it. :) Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: The OP uses `CreatedAtRoute(string routeName, object value)` which does seem like the correct overload.

Comment: It turns out not to be, because the `value` does not specify the `id` route value. Instead, he could make the `id` optional in the route definition, in which case it would work.

Comment: Doh! I think the first and second overloads are misleading and misconstrued.  Whenever a `Location` header is provided, **assuredly** it is necessary to provide **both** the pertinent route and `routeValues`.  In contrast, it is never necessary to supply content for the reply.  So again, those overloads are all jacked up IMHO.  In short, only the third overload has any value at this point.  Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: @BrentArias I agree. The `value` argument is odd and not required. The overloads really ought to be organized with `value` as the third argument.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin, Nice catch. I opened an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4454