# CreateAtRoute generating a 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to learn ASP.NET Core MVC and I am very green on this subject.

I have created a very simple webapi using `EntityFrameworkCore` with simple DI injection to test my own understanding. The entity frame work with DI injection part works fine and records were written in the database correctly which is a relief. However, each time I added a record from postman using POST, my record got added to the database, but there was an error 500 in postman. I can not locate where the error occurred, but I think the error may happen in `CreateAtRoute`.

[image]

Below is the structure of my project, I include it in for the sake of completeness.

[image]

The record got added correctly in the database, so the entity framework and DI injection part should be fine. This is the command I put in postman

```
http://localhost:7575/api/receipt
```

and this was the record I added:
[image]

After hitting send, POSTMAN generated the error 500:

[image]
My controller code is attached below:

```
namespace TestReceipt2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ReceiptController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IReceiptRepository _receiptRepository;

        public ReceiptController(IReceiptRepository receiptRepository)
        {
            _receiptRepository = receiptRepository;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_receiptRepository.GetAll());
        }
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseCache(Duration =60, Location =ResponseCacheLocation.Client)]
        public IEnumerable<Receipt> GetAll()
        {
            return _receiptRepository.GetAll();
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}",Name ="GetReceipt")]
        public IActionResult Get(string id)
        {
            var Item = _receiptRepository.Find(id);
            if (Item==null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(Item);
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Receipt value)
        {
            if (value==null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            TryValidateModel(value);
            if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _receiptRepository.Add(value);
                }
                catch (System.Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetReceipt", new { controller = "Receipt", id = value.ID });
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Put(string id, [FromBody]Receipt value)
        {
            var receipt = _receiptRepository.Find(id);
            _receiptRepository.Update(value);
            return new NoContentResult();
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(string id)
        {
            _receiptRepository.Remove(id);
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, I am very new to all these ASP.NET Core MVC stuff, the error maybe something trivial caused by my inexperience or obvious.. or may not be an error? I just do not know why Postman was complaining and I do not know how to find out which internal error it was referring to...

Any pointer to help me reveal this mystery would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core "CreatedAtRoute" Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560239/asp-net-core-createdatroute-failure)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload of CreatedAtRoute. Use the overload that takes three arguments instead.

[A very similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36560239/2867656)