# Why nameof doesn't work with the CreationAtAction return statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a Web API using **.NET Core** ,when I send a post or an update to my web api, I am returning the resource. For that, at the end of each method, I am using `CreatedAtAction` method, where the first parameter is the action name.

When I am using a hard coded action name, `CreatedAtAction("GetBook", [...]` for example, it works. But when I am using `CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetBook), [...]` I got an error saying that no routes matches. Is there a particulary reason for that ?

Comment: @remario add a watcher and check what nameof(GetBook) return

Comment: It would be very surprising if `nameof(GetBook)` didn't return `"GetBook"`. Most likely your routing problem is unrelated to the use of `nameof`.

Comment: You are using `CreatedAtAction("GetBook", [...]` with "GetBook", but using **nameof** with `CreatedAtRoute`. Two methods are different. The error is obvious, as you don't have any routes defined with the name "GetBook". Try using `CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetBook), [...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreatedAtRoute`  is a helper method which **inherits from ControllerBase** .  What `CreatedAtRoute()` does  is  **simply returning a new CreatedAtRouteResult(routeName, routeValues, value)**  . There is no dark magic at all :

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a <see cref="CreatedAtRouteResult"/> object that produces a <see cref="StatusCodes.Status201Created"/> response.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="routeName">The name of the route to use for generating the URL.</param>
/// <param name="routeValues">The route data to use for generating the URL.</param>
/// <param name="value">The content value to format in the entity body.</param>
/// <returns>The created <see cref="CreatedAtRouteResult"/> for the response.</returns>
[NonAction]
public virtual CreatedAtRouteResult CreatedAtRoute(string routeName, object routeValues, object value)
=> new CreatedAtRouteResult(routeName, routeValues, value);
```

The `CreatedAtRoute` method is often used within a ApiController , and the third parameter will be used as the content of response  . Let's say an action method :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "HelloDetails")]
    public IActionResult GetDetail(int id)
    {
        var result = new MyItem() {
            Id=id,
            ItemName="sherry"
        }; 
        
        return new JsonResult(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] MyItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        
        return CreatedAtRoute("HelloDetails", new { id = item.Id }, item);
    }
```

Use Postman to test ,the result is a 201 response. The response's body contains details of the entity we created and the response's Location header contains a URI to the entity.

[image]

[image]

You could also have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36560599/10201850)

Comment: `CreatedAtAction(nameof(a), b, c)` - here a is the name of the GET endpoint, b is the ID to pass into that GET endpoint url and c is the created object. Have I understood it right?

Answer (score 2):

Look like you've mixed up  the `CreatedAt*Action*`  and `CreatedAt*Route*` methods. `nameof(GetBook)` should definitely return `"GetBook"`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2
It shows **CreatedAtAction**(nameof(GetBook), [...]) should work.