# Matching Route Problem with CreatedAtRoute method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have this piece of code:

```
[Route("api/ReceiptOrders/{receiptOrderNo}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReceiptPositionsController : ControllerBase
{
  //Code here...

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetReceiptOrderPositions")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetReceiptOrderPositions(string receiptOrderNo, [FromQuery] ReceiptPositionParameters parameters)
    {
       //code here...
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostReceiptOrderPositions(string receiptOrderNo, [FromBody] IEnumerable<ReceiptPositionForCreationDto> receiptPositions)
    {
      //Some code...
      var createdDataDTO = created data here
      return CreatedAtRoute("GetReceiptOrderPositions", new{createdDataDTO});
    }
}
```

The ReceiptPositionParameters class is a metadata to specify page numbers and page size etc...

```
public class ReceiptPositionParameters : RequestParameters
{
    public ReceiptPositionParameters()
    {
        OrderBy = "PositionKey";
    }
    public string? SearchTerm { get; set; }
    public bool IsBookable { get; set; }

}
```

The RequestParameters class is as follows:

```
public abstract class RequestParameters
{
    private const int MaxPageSize = 50;
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    private int _pageSize = 10;

    public int PageSize
    {
        get => _pageSize;
        set => _pageSize = (value > MaxPageSize) ? MaxPageSize : value;
    }

    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

When I try this code I get this exception:
*System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.*

I tried sending the receiptOrderNo instead/in addition to the createdDataDTO but I ended up with the same failure.

Here's an example of working URL:

```
https://localhost:7164/api/ReceiptOrders/RO-20220730-01/ReceiptPositions?IsBookable=true&PageNumber=1&PageSize=2
```

this is also a valid URL:

```
https://localhost:7164/api/ReceiptOrders/RO-20220730-01/ReceiptPositions
```

Comment: @madreflection I tried that too. Same problem. I think the program doesn't get it because of the parameter "Parameter".

I have the same method in another example where the HTTPGet method doesn't have the Parameter input

Comment: Try `return CreatedAtRoute("GetReceiptOrderPositions", new{receiptOrderNo});`

Comment: I removed the comment because there wasn't enough information to know that it was correct. You need to pass it an object that has properties that match the parameters of `GetReceiptOrderPositions`. You haven't shown the definitions of any of the other classes involved so your question is incomplete. You need to post a [mre]. What you've posted is too minimal.

Comment: @Chetan same problem

Comment: Can you share how the route of `GetReceiptOrderPositions` looks like in route mapping?

Comment: @Chetan 
I changed the description of the problem. some details were added

Comment: You don't have a route with name `GetReceiptOrderPositions` in the route map table. Your route is mapped at the top of the controller. So when you do `CreateAtRoute` it is not able to find a route with that name in the route map table. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: You probably wanted `CreatedAtAction` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry guys but all the proposed solutions didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
I need to put all the Parameters in the 2nd parameter like this form:

```
return CreatedAtRoute(
            routeName: "GetReceiptOrderPositions",
            routeValues: new { orderNo = orderNo, pageNumber = pageNumber, pageSize = pageSize etc... },
            value: "returned data" or null);
```

so the third one is not optional if you want to send parameter!

many thanks for [the guys who solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36560599/4743192):